# How do I reshape a layer for LSTM input?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to make the neural network in [this flowchart](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14XeineDi1pKQAVwhf-t0zkoykxJ7rm6m) but am not sure how to reshape the inputs or my custom embedding layer. It was created by a Google TensorFlow Hub module for giving the LSTM layers the 3-dimensional inputs.

Normally, when we need to reshape something for an LSTM network, we reshape the input - not another layer. Specifically - according to [How to Reshape Input Data for Long Short-Term Memory Networks in Keras](https://machinelearningmastery.com/reshape-input-data-long-short-term-memory-networks-keras/) we want the shape to indicate:

- Samples: one sequence is one sample. A batch is comprised of one or more samples.
- Time Steps: one time step is one point of observation in the sample.
- Features: one feature is one observation at a time step.

My code:

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from tensorflow.dtypes import as_string
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

embedding_shape = (32,32,32)
def embedding(x):
    module = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-en-dim128/1")
    return_tensor = module(tf.squeeze(tf.cast(x, tf.string)),signature="default", as_dict=True)["default"]
    try:
      return_tensor = tf.cast(return_tensor,tf.float32)
    except ValueError:
      print("Embedding function could not cast return_tensor to float")
    print ("Returning tensor with shape",return_tensor.get_shape())
    return return_tensor
def split(x,col):
    return tf.reshape(x[:,col:col+1],(-1,))
def flatten_tensor(x):
    flat_tensor = tf.keras.backend.flatten(x)
    assert (len(flat_tensor.get_shape())==1)
    return flat_tensor
def flatten_layer():
    return Lambda(flatten_tensor)

input_questions = Input(shape=(1,),dtype=tf.string)
questions_embedded = Lambda(embedding)(input_questions)
questions_rnn = LSTM(32,return_sequences=True)(questions_embedded)
left_branch_outputs = questions_rnn
input_context = Input(shape=(1,),dtype=tf.string)
context_embedded = Lambda(embedding)(input_context)
context_rnn = LSTM(32,return_sequences=True)(context_embedded)
right_branch_outputs = context_rnn
main_branch_inputs = Add()([left_branch_outputs,right_branch_outputs])
main_outputs = Dense(24,activation="softmax")(Flatten()(main_branch_inputs))
answers_network_rnn = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_questions,input_context],outputs=main_outputs)
answers_network_rnn.compile("adam","categorical_crossentropy",metrics=['accuracy'])
answers_network_rnn_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('answers_network-rnn-best.h5', verbose=1, monitor='val_acc',save_best_only=True, mode='auto')

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.tables_initializer()])
    X_2_train_text = np.array(
      [["how much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood",
        "a woodchuck would chuck as much wood as a woodchuck could chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood"]
      ,["who sells seashells by the seashore",
       "she sells seashells by the seashore"]])
    y=session.run(tf.one_hot(np.array([23,0]),24))
    print(X_2_train_text.shape)
    print(y.shape)
    x = np.hsplit(X_2_train_text,2)
    print(x)
    answers_network_rnn.fit(x=x,y=y)
```

The neural network should be able to output a 1-dimensional vector for each sample.

#### Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-cb0103df9a44> in <module>()
     13   x = np.hsplit(X_2_train_text,2)
     14   print(x)
---> 15   answers_network_rnn.fit(x=x,y=y)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    878           initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
    879           steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
--> 880           validation_steps=validation_steps)
    881 
    882   def evaluate(self,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_arrays.py in model_iteration(model, inputs, targets, sample_weights, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_inputs, val_targets, val_sample_weights, shuffle, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, mode, validation_in_fit, **kwargs)
    327 
    328         # Get outputs.
--> 329         batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
    330         if not isinstance(batch_outs, list):
    331           batch_outs = [batch_outs]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   3074 
   3075     fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals,
-> 3076                                 run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
   3077     self._call_fetch_callbacks(fetched[-len(self._fetches):])
   3078     return nest.pack_sequence_as(self._outputs_structure,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1437           ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(
   1438               self._session._session, self._handle, args, status,
-> 1439               run_metadata_ptr)
   1440         if run_metadata:
   1441           proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
    526             None, None,
    527             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
--> 528             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
    529     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive
    530     # as there is a reference to status from this from the traceback due to

InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [2,24] vs. [32,24]
     [[{{node training_8/Adam/gradients/loss_21/dense_loss/mul_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs}}]]
```

Comment: As you use sentence-embedding, you encode the entirety of the sentence into a vector. So I don't really see the point of using LSTM here. 
You must ask yourself what are your TimeSteps and your features. In your case, naively, as your features are 1D 128 vectors, your timestep is 1. And a LSTM with a timestep of 1 is just a FC layer with tanh. 
Either your questions are related to each other, and you can batch process them,  or you should encode your words 1 by 1 (with Word2Vec, for example), and process them with sliding windows. If you're interested, I can develop a bit more in an answer.

Comment: @Lescurel: You should put that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy of @Lescurel:

As you use sentence-embedding, you encode the entirety of the sentence into a vector. So I don't really see the point of using LSTM here. You must ask yourself what are your TimeSteps and your features. In your case, naively, as your features are 1D 128 vectors, your timestep is 1. And a LSTM with a timestep of 1 is just a FC layer with tanh. Either your questions are related to each other, and you can batch process them, or you should encode your words 1 by 1 (with Word2Vec, for example), and process them with sliding windows.

Comment: guess he has sequence of Word2Vec means 2d sequence, right, and the rows in batch are just steps in sequence, right?